# How to get xcancel to work inside highlight?

Tags: highlighting, strikeout

```
\documentclass[oneside,9pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{cancel} 
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%
    \setul{\dp\strutbox}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox\relax}%
    %\setul{}{2em}
    \let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor
    \SOUL@stpreamble
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\highlight}[2]{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}

\newcommand{\myQuote}[4]{{\textsuperscript{\tiny\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{#2}{ #3$\langle$}}}\textcolor{#2}{\highlight{#1}{#4}}}

\newcommand{\Ben}[1]{\myQuote{gray}{blue}{Ben}{#1}} % Ben Franklin


\newcommand{\cancelMe}[1]{\xcancel{\textit{\tiny #1}}}


\begin{document}

% https://www.keepinspiring.me/benjamin-franklin-quotes/

\Ben{``If you are active and prosperous, or young, or in good health, it may be easier for you to augment your means than to diminish your wants. But if you are wise, you will do both at the same time, young or \cancelMe{old}, rich or poor, sick or well; and if you are wise, you will do both in such a way as to augment the general happiness of society.''}

\vspace{0.5in}

\Ben{``If you are active and prosperous, or young, or in good health, it may be easier for you to augment your means than to diminish your wants. But if you are wise, you will do both at the same time, young or''} \cancelMe{old}, \Ben{``rich or poor, sick or well; and if you are wise, you will do both in such a way as to augment the general happiness of society.''}

\end{document}
```

I get an "extra {" error when I try to place the `cancelMe` inside the `\Ben` macro.  I guess its a nesting problem with "soul" and its `hl` macro???

Ideally, I would like the tiny text to be vertically centered on the same line.

I would prefer the first output with the appropriate "old" crossed out.  It is throwing an error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put braces around `\cancelMe{old}`. The `\highlight` command from the `soul` package iterates over the quotation token by token and processes them separately. This way, `\cancelMe` is executed without its argument. When putting braces around it, `\cancelMe` moves around together with its argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,9pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{cancel} 
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%
    \setul{\dp\strutbox}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox\relax}%
    %\setul{}{2em}
    \let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor
    \SOUL@stpreamble
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\highlight}[2]{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}

\newcommand{\myQuote}[4]{{\textsuperscript{\tiny\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{#2}{ #3$\langle$}}}\textcolor{#2}{\highlight{#1}{#4}}}

\newcommand{\Ben}[1]{\myQuote{gray}{blue}{Ben}{#1}} % Ben Franklin


\newcommand{\cancelMe}[1]{\xcancel{\textit{\tiny #1}}}


\begin{document}

% https://www.keepinspiring.me/benjamin-franklin-quotes/

\Ben{``If you are active and prosperous, or young, or in good health, it may be easier for you to augment your means than to diminish your wants. But if you are wise, you will do both at the same time, young or {\cancelMe{old}}, rich or poor, sick or well; and if you are wise, you will do both in such a way as to augment the general happiness of society.''}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So because of this "brace" issue, is it possible to nest quotes:  ```\Ben{``I was talking to George who said: \George{``I like my vino.''} and I had to laugh because his wood teeth stained because he would drink so much red wine.''}```